# Long Press Gesture not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

Long press gesture not working for me when I use this method `(void)longpressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)`. Gesture is not called when I long press on label.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    array =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello",@"we",@"Are",@"Swift", nil];
    int ypoint = 60;
    for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
        label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, ypoint, 300, 200)];
        label.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        label.text =[array objectAtIndex:i];
        [label setTag:i];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        ypoint = ypoint +70;
    }
    [label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    longPressGesture =[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longpressed:)];
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.6;
    longPressGesture.delegate = self;
    [label addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)longpressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
     if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            UILabel *myLabel= (UILabel *)gesture.view ;
            NSInteger myLabelTag =[myLabel tag];
            NSString *nameString=[array objectAtIndex:myLabelTag];
            NSLog(@"%@",nameString);                
     }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer  {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Did it at least trigger the method or what?

Comment: yes i m debug  it is not called single time

Comment: It means that the behavior is not triggered. You probably can find the issue based on this.

Comment: On clicking on label i am getting wrong tag . when i m click  hello,we they give tag 1 for both , and when we click on are and swift they give me tag 3. Which take wrong index of array.

Comment: check my answer, you are only registering the last label's gesture recognition

Answer (score 7):

Set `userInteractionEnabled = true` property to your label.

Answer (score 1):

try this one as long press is recognised,

```
-(void)longpressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
  {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) 
       {
        return;
        }  
                      //UILabel *myLabel= (UILabel *)gesture.view ;
                      NSInteger myLabelTag =[label tag];
                      NSString *nameString=[array objectAtIndex:myLabelTag];
                      NSLog(@"%@",nameString);                

  }
```

Comment: working but  not shown right element they show onlu last element

Comment: what do you mean by showing only right element ? showing only last element ? That means tag for labels are not properly set.

Comment: Whats exact issue now ? Please be specific & clear, let us know issues neatly. Post screenshot here, so that I can help you.

Comment: On clicking on label i am getting wrong tag . when i m click  "hello, we"  they give tag 1 for both , and when we click on are and swift they give me tag 3. Which take wrong index of array

Comment: That itself means tag is going wrong, try to set debug at for (int i=0 ;i<[array count]; i++) and check whether tag that is assigned to label is in correct order.

Comment: i do r&d then i got result label does not property tag button has tag property when i am replace label by button it shown right order for me.

Comment: Good then. Add custom button with clear background on label. Set tag to them.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
array =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello",@"we",@"Are",@"Swift", nil];
longPressGesture =[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longpressed:)];
longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.6;
longPressGesture.delegate = self;

int ypoint =60;
for (int i=0 ;i<[array count]; i++)
{
    label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, ypoint, 300, 200)];
    label.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    label.text =[array objectAtIndex:i];
    [label setTag:i];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    label.backgroundColor  = [UIColor redColor];
    [label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [label addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

    ypoint   = ypoint +70;
}
```

it works fine after making changes in your code

Answer (score 0):

i tried on my Xcode,and i find that 
the

`label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, ypoint, 300, 200)];`
your definition has some problems,here you should define a new label,instead of use the global variable.
change to this

`UILabel *newLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, ypoint, 300, 200)];`

Answer (score 0):

As per your last comment that you are getting wrong tag for label when you click on it.

It is because you have use a global object `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` recogniser for all labels.

You need to add separate gesture recogniser for all labels which will be unique for each label.

So create local gesture recogniser when you create label, so your code will be now:

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) 
{
    // Label creation code...

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture =[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longpressed:)];
   // gesture settings...

   // Add UILongPressGestureRecognizer for each label.
   [label addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding the labels on top of it. Only the last one's gesture recognition method is gets registered. Try tapping on the bottom of the view. Change the color  to red and press and hold the bottom area it will work.

```
label.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
```

If you want to add gesture recognition to *all the labels* then place it inside the for loop. But why are you using a label, use a button instead to avoid the complication.